# getting [object HTMLDivElement] instead of HTML append in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ionic-framework, pdf-generation, html-to-pdf

I am trying to generate pdf with the help of html for that purpose I need to append html tags. But it give me output like

```
 [object HTMLDivElement]
```

I think i making mistake while appending html . how i can resolve it?

```
      PDFGenerator.fromData(`<html lang="en"><head> <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../theme.css"></head><body><div id="app">${this.$refs.order.$el}</div></body></html>`, options)
        .then(() => "ok")
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

Comment: You're probably looking for the `outerHTML` property

Comment: let me check may be you are right

Answer (score 0):

`${this.$refs.order.$el}` is a `div` element. If you want its HTML content, get its `outerHTML` property.

Comment: it seems like it is getting data inside the tags because i can't see style and tags implementation in pdf file